# Select dimension to perform FFT with FFTW in C

Tags: c, fftw

I have some data stored as `D[x][y][z][t]` and I would like to perform fft using the `fftw` library but only on t dimension, which means that I would like to obtain the frequency response of this matrix. Of course `D[x][y][z][t]` is simply a wrapper for a vectorized array (since this kind of arrays can be used as arguments in `fftw`). In MATLAB it is possible to compute it directly but in `c` I simply cannot find any kind of reference, even in `fftw` references. Any ideas?

Array is stored as `D[l + k*Nt + j*Nt*Nz + i*Nt*Nz*Ny]` where `i,j,k,l` are the indices for `x,y,z,t` and the corresponding array sizes are `Nx, Ny, Nz, Nt`. What I would like is the computation of FFT on `t` dimension with `Nt` points, consequently.

The corresponding plan should be like `myplan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(Nt, &D[0], &out_array, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` but I am not sure if this will work. I would like the output array to be a similar sized array containing the FFT transfored `x,y,z` in the same manner as with the original D array. Note that `output_array` is a complex array allocated the same way as the double `D` one.

Comment: Please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people at least see your attempt on this

Comment: I have posted what I would like to do. An example is not viable at this point as I don't know from where to start. I am familiar with 1D Fourier transform but I was wondering how to perform 1D on a specific dimension only

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fft the n-th dimension of your data above using FFTW. What you can do is copy out the "column" along the dimension in question and do many ffts and copy the data back. In other words, you would plan your FFT as one or many one dimensional ffts of correct length. Copy the data "column" by "column" into the memory that you have prepared for the operation, do fft along that data copy back to where it belongs.

Another, more expensive operation would be to permute the data, so that the first dimension is the one you would like to fft and go over all columns.

As part of my PhD, I wrote this library for medical image reconstruction (https://github.com/kvahed/codeare). The DFT implementation allows for fft along any dimension, but it's done the way I described: 
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/ft/DFT.hpp. This is C++, but you will get the idea. Look for the function

```
template<class T> inline static Matrix<T> fft (
  const Matrix<T>& in, size_t dim, bool shift, bool fwd) noexcept;
```

The precision specific code is here:
https://github.com/kvahed/codeare/blob/master/src/matrix/ft/FFTWTraits.hpp

Answer (score 0):

This is actually straightforward for your specific case and can be generalized for arbitrary dimensions. Your objective is to take a series of FFTs in the 't' dimension, so you just need to tell FFTW the memory layout of the data. If you just want to do an FFT in the t dimension an "out-of-place" implementation would be something like the following

```
int rank=1;
const int * N={Nx,Ny,Nz,Nt};
int howmany=Nx*Ny*Nz;
double *in = D;
const int *inembed=NULL;
int istride=1; 
int idist=Nt;
fftw_complex *out = Df;
const int *onembed = NULL;
int ostride=1; 
int odist = (Nt+2)/2;
unsigned flags = FFTW_ESTIMATE;

fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(rank, &N[3], howmany, 
                                        D, inembed,istride, idist, 
                                        DF, onembed, ostride, odist, flags);
```

See http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html for more details, you'll need to respect the particular memory requirements for the r2c transform in the output array.